# Directory API get organization unit for by userid and add user to a organization unit

Tags: google-directory-api

How can I add a user to an organization unit and get the organization unit information by user id using directory API?

Is it something like this?

```
List<OrgUnit> list = new ArrayList<OrgUnit>();
OrgUnit ou= new OrgUnit();
ou.setName(orgunit);
getDirectoryService().orgunits().insert(username, ou).execute();
```

and

```
OrgUnit ou = getDirectoryService().orgunits().get(userid, list).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to update org unit by User object.
    User user=getDirectoryService().users().get(username.execute();
   user.setOrgUnitPath(orgunit);
   getDirectoryService().users().update(username, user).execute();

To get org unit for  user: 
    User user=getDirectoryService().users().get(username).execute();
    return user.getOrgUnitPath();